# Django 1.9 ImportError when running migrate, but not runserver

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-settings, django-migrations, cookiecutter-django

I'm trying to run a new migration on a new Django 1.9 project but I'm getting an ImportError that seems to conflict with *runserver*. I'm running these commands from the <project> directory which includes the manage.py file.

Details:

- Django 1.9
- Using cookiecutter-django
- **runserver** references the settings file
- **migrate** produces an import error
- In my local .env file, I have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.local
- Settings are in <project>/config/settings/...
- I am running the project from within a virtualenv

**Commands & Error:**

```
$ django-admin.py migrate --settings=config.settings.local
.....
ImportError: No module named config.settings.local



$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

January 09, 2016 - 13:33:32
Django version 1.9, using settings 'config.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Er, because you're passing settings to migrate but not to runserver. Why don't you run migrate with manage.py like you do runserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `manage.py` instead of `django-admin.py`

```
python manage.py migrate --settings=config.settings.local
```

Comment: That answered it. I'll mark it correct once I can - thanks for the help, really appreciate it!